# Default folder for the FileUpload Control in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to Convert Office Word Document to HTML and display it in browser in ASP.Net so my code below is working fine but the only change that i want to make is that i don't want to use the FileUpload control, instead i want to set my default location to be simply as this: C:\Mydocument\ so how can i get rid of the fileupload control and just set my default location like above?

```
 protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      object missingType = Type.Missing;
      object readOnly = true;
      object isVisible = false;
      object documentFormat = 8;
      string randomName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
      object htmlFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName + ".htm";
      string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + randomName + "_files";

      //Upload the word document and save to Temp folder
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
      object fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

      //Open the word document in background
      ApplicationClass applicationclass = new ApplicationClass();
      applicationclass.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                                      ref readOnly,
                                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref  missingType,
                                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref isVisible,
                                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                                      ref missingType, ref missingType);
      applicationclass.Visible = false;
      Document document = applicationclass.ActiveDocument;

      //Save the word document as HTML file
      document.SaveAs(ref htmlFilePath, ref documentFormat, ref missingType,
                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                      ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType,
                      ref missingType);

      //Close the word document
      document.Close(ref missingType, ref missingType, ref missingType);

      //Delete the Uploaded Word File
      File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Temp/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));

      //Read the Html File as Byte Array and Display it on browser
      byte[] bytes;
      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(htmlFilePath.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);
        bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
        fs.Close();
      }
      Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
      Response.Flush();

      //Delete the Html File
      File.Delete(htmlFilePath.ToString());
      foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
      {
        File.Delete(file);
      }
      Directory.Delete(directoryPath);
      Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Your Code can only run if the client and web server are on the same pc, may be on the same internal network. Change it to a desktop app

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually fine how it is you just need to add it to a regular method that will be called when the page loads (or anywhere else you want it). I would probably still have it in a button click so it doesn't fire off every time the page is hit or refreshed. You just need to change your paths to a location on the server. In all places you have a mappath give it the server location of your documents folder. I removed all lines of code that didn't need to be changed for clarity.

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var docPath = Server.MapPath("/yoursiteroot/documents/"); //your web server folder containing documents

      object htmlFilePath = docPath + randomName + ".htm";
      string directoryPath = docPath + randomName + "_files";

      //Upload the word document and save to Temp folder
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(docPath + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
      object fileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

      //Delete the Uploaded Word File
      File.Delete(docPath + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
}

<asp:Button ID="btnConvert" runat="server" text="Convert To HTML" click="Upload" />
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'C:/Users/files/Desktop/' is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected

Comment: You can't use your local file system. You can Server.MapPath to the file location on your server only.

Comment: I am getting an error because randomName is not specified in the current context

Comment: Which is true, you need to define randomName in scope. string randomName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); like you are in the other method. Keep in mind my answer is the short version of your code. You'll need all of the same variables that you needed in your other method. I just changed the parts you'll need to change.